# Async tasks in java rest webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, optimization, asynchronous

I am currently working on order management system for ecommerce portal

The backend are rest webservices in java while the front end is angular js.

The rest service in java does many tasks when an order is placed /updated

1. store/update order and items in the order in the db
2. Notify 3rd party logistics regd this order
3. send email notification to the customer
4. send sms notification to the customer
   etc

We already have an async queue implemented for another feature using blocking queue.

```
1. use the same queue(current size is 200 and is in memory) and post to it
2. create a new queue inside the rest webservice application
3. integrate with 3rd party queues.
```

Can someone give insights on #3? or is it wise to go for #1 or #2?

Comment: Stackoverflow is *not* a recommendation site. Further, it makes no sense to give you any kind of recommendation without being familiar with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Order management of e-commerce portal is not a simple problem.  It will most likely have scalability requirements and using simple [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for async processing will not be a good idea.

JVM based Blocking Queue is in-memory queue and requires producers and consumers to be running in same JVM process.

For sending emails whenver a customer places a new order, you need to ensure that email was really sent and application restarts does not result in loss of data present in Blocking Queue.

Hence, most likely you should use an out-of-process Queue systems such as [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) or [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or equivalent.